# Retrieve X and Y of SVG Text

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some SVG text on my page and I want to get the x and y coordinates of it and store it in a local variable.

When I run `console.log(this)` I get:

```
<text class="myClass" x="400" y="330">This is not text.</text>
```

So I thought I have the right selection, I just need to narrow it down. So I tried: `console.log(this.y)`, but then I got some weird object:

```
SVGAnimatedLengthList {BaseVal: SVGLengthList, animVal: SVGLengthList}
```

And no where in that object was anything to do with the value of my text's `y` position.

**Question:** How can I store the `y` value of my SVG text in a local variable? Is using `this` wrong? I mean it seems like it *could* work, seeing as the `y` value correctly comes up from `console.log(this)`. Basically I want something like:

```
var yValue = this.y
```

where this.y gives the correct value (y=330 in my case)

Comment: `this.getAttribute('y');`???

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That was it, thank you! I guess my fundamentals are weak :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated by SMIL and by the fact that you can have multiple values e.g. x="300 400 500"

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].y.baseVal[0].value);
```

```html
<svg>
<text class="myClass" x="400" y="330">This is not text.</text>
</svg>
```

Alternatively in the simple case you can call text.getAttribute("x") and get the value as a string

Comment: Alternatively, `this.getStartPositionOfChar(0)`.

Comment: @ccprog that will give a completely different answer on RTL text

Comment: ...or if there was a dx attribute, or if the OP wanted to know viewport coordinates...starting from the snippet in the question, it would be correct.